# Information On And Feasibility Of An Intel AMT ME Detector?

Tags: performance, cpu, intel

Reading about the [Intel AMT](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/intel-active-management-technology.html) recently it seems to exist as a chip within the CPU which acts independently but shares all the buses with the CPU.

Since the CPU and AMT components share buses, does this mean when the AMT is active you would be able to detect it from the R/W speed to RAM, the NIC, etc from the CPU?

Does this mean you are getting less than you paid for in terms of CPU performance when the AMT is active, or do the bus speeds act as the choke point, allowing the CPU to still perform at its peak rating?

Are there any existing tools to detect when AMT is active?  (Considering it a backdoor for the context of this post.)  Any suggestions on how to write such a tool if not?